# Trying to connect to Firebase but crashes when adding button

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set an app to just enter something on the textEdit and change it in real time in the Firebase database. The app works just fine if I just do `myRef = database.getReference("");` but when I try to add the editing feature it just crashes the app.

This is the code:

```
package com.example.usuario.firebase;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    Button enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    EditText editar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView ver = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myRef.setValue("test");

        enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myRef.setValue(editar.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.usuario.firebase/com.example.usuario.firebase.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2785)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6326)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
    at com.example.usuario.firebase.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:18)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2616)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: please post stack trace

Comment: Problem is that Android Studio doesnt show up any error when compiling it
http://prntscr.com/h6jzji

Comment: @Kiraii look at Android monitor tab

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vbDideZg

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.usuario.firebase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    Button enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    EditText editar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView ver = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myRef.setValue("test");

        enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myRef.setValue(editar.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove this `myRef.setValue("test");`
And replace this `myRef.setValue(editar.getText().toString());` with this `myRef.child("test").setValue(editar.getText().toString());`.